# Angular bind not displaying

Tags: angularjs, format, bind

Bit of a crazy one, certainly a very very frustrating one!

I have a pretty basic ng-repeat going on and it's working in 95% of the cases. However a few of the binds just aren't displaying.
Basic use:

```
<p>{{result.thingy}}</p>
```

Nothing shows up in the HTML
However if I use

```
<p>{{result.thingy | json}}</p>
```

Then it displays, but with quotemarks around it.
So the data is there, how come it won't show? Is it somehow an invalid type?
I have ported this across from another Angular app which displays it fine, so I suppose there might be a difference in the Angular version or something like that, but this seems crazy to me.

It also shows if I use `| number`

Apologies, I can't share the data apart from that when I print the full JSON to the screen, it looks like:

```
"thingy": { "pounds": "174", "pence": "08" }
```

Comment: Can't tell anything without the data and the HTML

Comment: Hi, just added a couple of extra lines.

Comment: Theres no property called `thingy`

Comment: there is:
`"thingy": { "pounds": "174", "pence": "08" }`

Comment: And you just want to display this as `{ "pounds": "174", "pence": "08" }` ?

Comment: Look at what result is in each of the child scopes created by ng-repeat 
`var i = 0;
for(var cs = scope.$$childHead; cs; cs = cs.$$nextSibling) {
    console.log('child'+i+' - '+angular.toJson(cs.result));
}`

Comment: Sorry, where do I write that?